# Test details not provided with Guard + Rspec under Ubuntu with Gem libnotify

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, tdd, spork, guard

I'm setting up the testing of my rails apps with the combination of `Guard`, `Spork` and `Rspec`. 
Everything seems to be correctly installed and I got the notification of the tests through `libnotify`.

However, in the console where Guard is running, I was expecting the details result of the tests. Nevertheless detailed results do not appear.

What I see instead is for instance:

```
Spork is ready and listening on 8989!
Spork server for RSpec successfully started
Guard::RSpec is running, with RSpec 2!
Running: spec/controller/sessions_controller_spec.rb spec/controllers/groups_controller_spec.rb
Running tests with args ["--drb", "-f", "progess", "-r", "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-rspec-1.1.0/lib/guard/rspec/formatters/notification_rspec.rb", "-f", "Guard::RSpec::Formatter::NotificationRSpec", "--out", "/dev/null", "spec/controllers/groups_controller_spec.rb", "spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb]...
Done

>  >
```

When this is peformed, I got a pop-up in the notification area of Ubuntu telling for instance:

```
RSpec results
28 examples, 21 failures
in 52.6711 seconds
```

Fair enough. The test is not passing. Ok, I don't care but I would like to have the details of the tests such the one received when using common Rspec in console through the `bundle exec rspec spec/` command.

Do you have an idea how to make the details displayed in such a case?

I noticed in the log of `Guard` the `args` being used such as `--out` and `/dev/null` and I may expect that the issue is coming from them but then the question is how to change these parameters?

Thanks a lot for your valuable help!

Here is the relevant content of my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rspec-rails', :group => [:development, :test]

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'guard-spork'
  gem 'spork'
  gem 'rb-inotify'
  gem 'libnotify'
end
```

Comment: The `--out` parameter applies only to the previous formatter, in this case to `Guard::RSpec::Formatter::NotificationRSpec` (see `rspec --help`), so the progress formatter (`-f progress`) should still write to STDOUT.

Comment: Yeah - except it doesn't! I have the same problem. It's very strange that there's no way to see _what_ is failing. For now, I just run rspec in a separate window (using --drb) which isn't too slow. But it's still plenty redundant.

Comment: I have same problem unfortunately.